# How to use certain rows of a dataframe in a formula

Tags: python, pandas, numpy, csv

So I have multiple data frames and all need the same kind of formula applied to certain sets within this data frame. I got the locations of the sets inside the df, but I don't know how to access those sets.
This is my code:

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np 
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt #might used/need it later to check the output
df = pd.read_csv('Dalfsen.csv')
l = []
x = []
y = []
#the formula(trendline)
def rechtzetten(x,y): 
    a = (len(x)*sum(x*y)- sum(x)*sum(y))/(len(x)*sum(x**2)-sum(x)**2)
    b = (sum(y)-a*sum(x))/len(x)
    y1 = x*a+b
    print(y1)

METING = df.ID.str.contains("<METING>") #locating the sets
indicatie = np.where(METING == False)[0] #and saving them somewhere


if n in df[n] != indicatie & n+1 != indicatie: #attempt to add parts of the set in l
    append.l
elif n in df[n] != indicatie & n+1 == indicatie: #attempt defining the end of the set and using the formula for the set
    append.l
    rechtzetten(l.x, l.y)
else: #emptying the storage for the new set
    l = []
```

`indicatie` has the following numbers:

```
 0  12  13  26  27  40  41  53  54  66  67  80  81  94  95 108 109 121
 122 137 138 149 150 162 163 177 178 190 191 204 205 217 218 229 230 242
 243 255 256 268 269 291 292 312 313 340 341 373 374 401 402 410 411 420
 421 430 431 449 450 468 469 487 488 504 505 521 522 538 539 558 559 575
 576 590 591 604 605 619 620 633 634 647
```

Because my df looks like this:

```
ID,NUM,x,y,nap,abs,end
<PROFIEL>not used data
<METING>data</METING>
<METING>data</METING>
...
<METING>data</METING>
<METING>data</METING>
</PROFIEL>,,,,,,
<PROFIEL>not usde data
...
</PROFIEL>,,,,,,
```

tl;dr I'm trying to use a formula in each profile as shown above. I want to edit the data between 2 numbers of the list indicatie.
**For example:**
the fucntion rechtzetten(x,y) for the x and y df.x&df.y[1:11](Because [0]&[12] are in the list indicatie.) And then the same for [14:25] etc. etc.
What I try to avoid is typing the following hundreds of times manually:

```
x_#=df.x[1:11]
y_#=df.y[1:11]
rechtzetten(x_#,y_#)
```

Answer (score 0):

I cant understand your question clearly, but if you want to replace a specific column of your pandas dataframe with a numpy array, you could simply assign it :

```
df['Column'] = numpy_array
```

Can you be more clear ?

Comment: I've edited the question. In short, I've made a list where the beginning and the end of the (sub)sets are. I want to take those x and y data, of the (sub)set, and put them for each (sub)set apart in the formula.

Comment: Okay, still not clear as to what this block does : `if n in df[n] != indicatie & n+1 != indicatie:` `#attempt to add parts of the set in l`
    `append.l`
`elif n in df[n] != indicatie & n+1 == indicatie:` `#attempt defining the end of the set and using the formula for the set`
    `append.l`
    `rechtzetten(l.x, l.y)`                                  For accessing a particular row in a dataframe use df.loc[row_number], maybe you can use a for loop and pass the individual values of x and y to the function.  `for row in indicatie:` `s = df.loc[row]` `x,y = s.x, s.y` `rechtzetten(x,y)`

Comment: It's my attempt at the example I typed. I know how to access a particular row, but I need to access them in sets like I mentioned. [1:11] and [14:25], [28:39] etc.

Comment: To access a series of rows, you can use `df.loc[1:11]`

Comment: That's not what i want. I could easily do that by df.x[1:11] and df.y[1:11]
I need to do that for atleast 44 other arrays in this file only. 
And i have another 15 files like this.
To do that manual takes a lot of time.